# Connect Java to a MySQL TCP/IP over SSH database

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, ssh

I'm trying to connect to the MySQL server "Over SSH" but I keep getting an error.

Here is the code.

```
int lport = 
String host = " "
String rhost = " ";
int rport = 
String user = " ";

String dbuserName = " ";
String dbpassword = " ";
String dburl = "  ";

String driverName = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String driverName2 = "org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver";

session = null;
con = null;
try { 
    final java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
    config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
    final JSch jsch = new JSch();
    session = jsch.getSession(user, host, 22);
    jsch.addIdentity("C:\\Users\\WAlnadi\\workspace\\AKCAPIAutomation\\lib\\FARM-8-9df40547.us-east-1.pem");
    session.setConfig(config);
    session.connect();
    session.setPortForwardingL(rport, host, rport);
    System.out.println("Connected through SSH");
    final int assinged_port = session.setPortForwardingL(lport, rhost, rport);
    System.out.println("localhost:" + assinged_port + " -> " + rhost + ":" + rport);
    System.out.println("Port Forwarded");

    //mysql database connectivity
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

    //String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:" + rport + "/" + db;
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(dburl, dbuserName, dbpassword);

    System.out.println("Mysql Database connection established");
    System.out.println("DONE");        

    return true;
    } catch (final Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();return false;
    } finally {
        if (con != null && !con.isClosed()) {
            System.out.println("Closing Database Connection");
            con.close();
        }
        if (session != null && session.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Closing SSH Connection");
            session.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

and the errors :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
```

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.